# React Native - how to change style and image of a view onPress

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, touchablehighlight

I have three TouchableHighlight elements wrapping three views (aligned next to each other). Onpress I would like to change the style (backgroundColor) and image of the view (the pressed view would become active).

- active view - backgroundColor `<View style={styles.circle}>` should become 'red' and image source should be 'arrow-win-active.png' `<Image source={require('../images/arrow-win.png')} style={styles.arrowWin}></Image>`
- the two other views remain the same

What would be the best way to do it?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    View,
    ListView,
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native'

const changeStyle = () => {
    console.log('change style')
}

const appView = (game, date) =>
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.step}>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={styles.pickContainer}>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => changeStyle()} style={{flex:1}}>
                    <View style={styles.pickWrapper}>
                        <View style={styles.circle}>
                            <Image source={require('../images/arrow-win.png')} style={styles.arrowWin}></Image>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}>
                    <View style={styles.pickWrapper}>
                        <View style={styles.circle}>
                            <Image source={require('../images/arrow-draw.png')} style={styles.arrowDraw}></Image>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}>
                    <View style={styles.pickWrapper}>
                        <View style={styles.circle}>
                            <Image source={require('../images/arrow-win.png')} style={styles.arrowWin}></Image>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e1e1e1'
},
step: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderLeftWidth: 5,
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2,
    },
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
},
heading: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 15,
    color: '#333333',
},
pickContainer: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
pickWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
},
circle: {
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    width: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
arrowWin: {
    width: 34,
    height: 28,
},
arrowDraw: {
    width: 18,
    height: 8,
},
})

export default appView
```

Comment: Can you tell what style you want to replace with, what image you want to replace with? Its not clear from question whether all three images are to appear together or do they rotate on press?

Comment: Sure, I've just updated my question with more details regarding the style. Any of the pressed views would become active and the two others inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `AppView` to class based component because you have to access `state`.

```
import React. {Component} from 'react'
import {
  View,
  ListView,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native'

class AppView extends Component {
  state = {
    isPlayer1ButtonActive: false,
    isDrawButtonActive: false,
    isPlayer2ButtonActive: false,
  }

  activateButton = buttonToActivate => {
    const newState = Object.assign(
      {}, 
      {
        isPlayer1ButtonActive: false,
        isDrawButtonActive: false,
        isPlayer2ButtonActive: false,
      }, 
      {[buttonToActivate]: true},
    )
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  render() {
    const {isPlayer1ButtonActive, isDrawButtonActive, isPlayer2ButtonActive} = this.state

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.step}>
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={styles.pickContainer}>
              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => activateButton('isPlayer1ButtonActive')} style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={styles.pickWrapper}>
                  <View style={[styles.circle, isPlayer1ButtonActive && styles.circleActive]}>
                    <Image 
                      source={isPlayer1ButtonActive ? require('../images/arrow-win-active.png') : require('../images/arrow-win.png')} 
                      style={styles.arrowWin} 
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>

              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => activateButton('isDrawButtonActive')}  style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={styles.pickWrapper}>
                  <View style={[styles.circle, isDrawButtonActive && styles.circleActive]}>
                    <Image 
                      source={isDrawButtonActive ? require('../images/arrow-draw-active.png') : require('../images/arrow-draw.png')} 
                      style={styles.arrowDraw} 
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>

              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => activateButton('isPlayer2ButtonActive')}  style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={styles.pickWrapper}>
                  <View style={[styles.circle, isPlayer2ButtonActive && styles.circleActive]}>
                    <Image 
                      source={isPlayer2ButtonActive ? require('../images/arrow-win-active.png') : require('../images/arrow-win.png')} 
                      style={styles.arrowWin} 
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e1e1e1'
  },
  step: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderLeftWidth: 5,
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  heading: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 15,
    color: '#333333',
  },
  pickContainer: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  pickWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  circle: {
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    width: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  circleActive: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  arrowWin: {
    width: 34,
    height: 28,
  },
  arrowDraw: {
    width: 18,
    height: 8,
  },
})

export default AppView
```

Comment: Thanks for that it makes sense. One last question - would you say it would be better to using redux for this?

Comment: I would not use redux for small thing like this :) Anything else you want to add?

Comment: Right ok. Thanks for your help ;)